# How to concatenate a string and GETDATE() in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, string, concatenation, getdate

I need to insert a string (a comment) which should include a date. What I need is basically the following simple operation:

```
INSERT INTO [Table_1]
           ([textColumn])
     VALUES
           ('Date: ' + GETDATE())
GO
```

This however, returns the following error: *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Any quick fixes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

what is the date time format you need?

select one from here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx and convert it to a char as bellow

```
INSERT INTO [Table_1]
           ([textColumn])
     VALUES
           ('Date: ' +CONVERT(CHAR(10),  GETDATE(), 120))
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I needed. I ended up with this version:
`convert(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106)) -- Format: 09 Aug 2011`

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the column's definition, you can try to cast or convert the date to the desired type:

```
INSERT INTO [Table_1]
       ([textColumn])
 VALUES
       ('Date: ' + CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(max)))
GO
```

To format the date, use Convert, e.g.

```
 INSERT INTO [Table_1]
       ([textColumn])
 VALUES
       ('Date: ' + convert(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 101))
 GO
```

The last Parameter defines the format - see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding it as part of data, you can store only datetime in column append the text Date using SELECT statement

`select 'Date '+ CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(max))  from [Table_1`]

Answer (score 0):

In case one of output field is null, the combined output will be null.
To solve, try this

lname + ',' + space(1) + fname + space(1) + 
(case when mname is null then '' else mname end) as FullName

from: 
http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/concatenate-when-one-column-is-null-371723.html

I tried and it works!